Missing declaration in C code cause rust compiled library segfault
My debug result says that a declaration of functions and structs is needed before using them in C code, otherwise the called rust function will receive an invalid pointer.
Library code, compiled by cargo build
pub struct Context {
    arr: Vec<i16>,
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn ctx_gen() -> Box<Context> {
    Box::new(Context { arr: Vec::new() })
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn ctx_use(c: *const Context) {
    let Some(ctx) = (unsafe { c.as_ref() }) else { return };
    println!("arr len: {}", ctx.arr.len());
}

Test code, compiled by gcc -o cb test.c ./target/debug/librustapi.a
struct Context;
//struct Context *ctx_gen();
void ctx_use(struct Context *ctx);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct Context *ctx = ctx_gen();
    ctx_use(ctx);
    usleep(200 * 1000);
}

It crashes when run ./cb, and gdb says ctx_use received invalid pointer
(gdb) frame 1
#1  0x0000555555566fbf in rustapi::ctx_use (c=0x556422a0) at src/lib.rs:13
13          println!("arr len: {}", ctx.arr.len());
(gdb) p ctx
$1 = (*mut rustapi::Context) 0x556422a0
(gdb) p *ctx
Cannot access memory at address 0x556422a0

However, uncomment the 2nd line //struct Context *ctx_gen(); recompile, the test code works.
I'm curious. What does the declaration change?
---edit---
The code is wrong, there is a warning saying implicit declaration.
Just to confirm, print the address before ctx_gen return, and before calling ctx_use, here's the result, the value is truncated.
ctx_gen: 0x5687227d42a0
0x227d42a0


The prototype of a function that's not declared in C is implicitly int ctx_gen() which is obviously different and incompatible with struct Context *ctx_gen().

Will the implicit declaration force convert my return pointer to int? And I think the int is converted back to pointer when calling ctx_use.

It's UB to call a function with an incompatible prototype so anything can happen.

Ah I see! The pointer is 64bit integer, which lose precision when converted to int. Thank you. I'll debug to confirm this.

@Catau there's nothing to debug, the code is just wrong. Instead of trying to guess what's happening, fix the code.

Don't code in C90 — that's archaic. C99 and later all require functions to be declared before they're used (unless they're static functions, in which case the definition can serve as the declaration too).  Turn up the warnings on your C compiler.  Since you're using GCC, start with -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c18; you can add more warnings from there, but that's a basic starting point.
